# How to disable permanently Gmail spell checker

Tags: gmail, firefox, spell-check

By default when I compose an e-mail in Gmail, the spell checker is active.
To disable it, I need to activate context menu (right click) and select "Check Spelling" option to toggle it off. Is there any way to disable it on a permanent basis, so always when a I start composing an e-mail no spell checking is performed?

Browswer: Firefox 14.0.1, on Windows XP

Comment: As Firefox has updated multiple times, (current version is [118](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/118.0/releasenotes/)), it's very likely that the [currently accepted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/30469/88163) be obsolete regarding how to handle the spell-checking feature in Firefox. Questions specific about web browser settings are better suited for sites about installable software like [su], [apple.se], [ubuntu.se], [unix.se]. For a complete site list, look at https://stackexchange.com/sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@MrWhite](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/5434/mrwhite) pointed out in a question comment, is not an issue with Gmail configuration, but my browser's. I'm using Firefox 14.0.1 and the method to disable the spell checker (in order to avoid spell checking in Gmail composer) is deselecting the option in Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> "Check my spelling as I type".

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is also spell-checking in Gmail.
Official usage doc is there : [Fix spelling & grammar as you type in Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7987?hl=en) (article title as October 15, 2023)

<s>As far as I know, there is no way to disable. However, it is only shown when you explicitly require it so I don't think it can be bothering at any time.</s>

Editors note: The current article version mentions that it's possible to turn on / off :

- Grammar
- Spelling
- Autocorrect